# Any reason *not* to trade Fallen Legion Artifacts to Vulgrim?

Tags: darksiders

I've been playing Darksiders. In the course of beating the souls out of dumpsters, traffic cones, and sign posts, I discovered a Fallen Legion Artifact.

The game helpfully popped up "Ooh, take this to Vulgrim and be rewarded!" So I did, and on Vulgrim's interface there was a new "press R to trade artifacts". I did so... and nothing seemed to happen.

The button disappeared, so I think I *did* trade something, I'm just not sure what I did. What does trading artifacts to Vulgrim *do*, and is there any reason *not* to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the only purpose the Fallen Legion Artifacts exist (outside of achievements) is to be traded for souls.

There are a limited number and I do know some people don't trade them in to keep track of how many they still have to pick up, but having 1000/1000 the game myself, I can tell you its not a necessity.

For reference

```
Fallen Legion Soldier Artifact: 500 souls (there are 20)
Fallen Legion Champion Artifact: 1000 souls (there are 8)
Fallen Legion Overlord Artifact: 5000 souls (plus a wrath core, there is 1)
```

Comment: I found a page in the inventory screen which has a slot for each Fallen Legion artifact, so it seems it's not even useful to keep around for that.